# How can I read the IP of an VM via Powershell in C#?

Tags: c#, powershell, hyper-v

I want to read the IP of my virtual machines. For this I made a WindowsForms application and at the moment I am able to switch between my VMs, suspend or resume them and everything is working fine. For that I run powershell commands in C# code. My only problem is to get the IP-Addresses of my VMs. The reason is that I want to access the VMs via Remote Desktop after starting them.

What I tried so far is to create a PowerShell element and running the command to access the IPAdresses. So far so good, I can see the IPAdress of all of my machines, if I take a look into the PSObject, but I can't extract it into a variable.

I tried to convert it into an object and iterate over all types, what didn't work because I lose all information. I also tried running several Powershell command, unfortunately not successful. I tried to find the correct assembly to create a sepecific object to read those values, but I can't.

According to Visual Studio I should be able to access it with my PSMemberInfo object. And it should be of the type **Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.VMNetworkAdapter**, what you can see in the image I attached. But I can't find such type, nor I can find a specific assembly to include what allows me to create such a type. https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1A0L.jpg

Did anyone already tried something like that or has another idea how I can access the IPs?

```
PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
ps.AddCommand("Get-VM").AddParameter("Name", _name);
ps.AddStatement().AddCommand("Select").AddParameter("ExpandProperty", "Networkadapters");
ps.AddStatement().AddCommand("Select").AddParameter("IPAddresses");

Collection<PSObject> _c;
_c = ps.Invoke();

foreach (PSObject o in _c)
{
    PSMemberInfo s = o.Members["Networkadapters"];
    //Type listType = s.Value.GetType();
    //var values = s.Value;
}
```

Comment: I believe you can use `o.Properties["NetworkAdapters"].Value` to access PSObject members.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a snippet that works fine for me in a console app - adapt to suit your WinForms setup:

```
using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
{
    PowerShellInstance.AddScript(@"(Get-VM).NetworkAdapters.IPAddresses -match '^(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}$'");

    Collection<PSObject> PSOutput = PowerShellInstance.Invoke();

    foreach (PSObject outputItem in PSOutput)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(outputItem);
    }
}
```

Note that I've added a very basic RegEx to capture only the IPv4 addresses.  Remove it to get the IPv6 addresses as well

Also, it's often easier to offload the data processing to PowerShell, by sending a more complicated script that returns just the desired information (e.g. using a `PsCustomObject`), rather than having to deal with it once your back in your C# app.